# How to sort by two attributes - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2NtS/456/)

```
$(".listitems li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');
function sort_li(a, b){
    return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : ($(b).data('position2')) > ($(a).data('position2')) ? 1 : 0;    
}
```

How can I sort it by the first attribute `position` and then by the second `position2`

Result I want to get:

```
Item 24 40549
Item 24 40501
Item 24 40500
Item 3 14801
Item 3 14800
Item 1 90500
Item 0 0
Item 0 0
Item 0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code work based on the string comparison instead do subtraction for number based sorting.

```js
$(".listitems li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');

function sort_li(a, b) {
  // get the diff of `data-position`
  var diff = $(b).data('position') - $(a).data('position');
  // return the difference if it's not 0
  // else return the difference of `data-position2`
  return diff == 0 ? $(b).data('position2') - $(a).data('position2') : diff;
  // although you can use Logical Short-Circuit Evaluation
  // return $(b).data('position') - $(a).data('position') || $(b).data('position2') - $(a).data('position2');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listitems">
  <li data-position="24" data-position2="40500">Item 24 40500</li>
  <li data-position="1" data-position2="90500">Item 1 90500</li>
  <li data-position="0" data-position2="0">Item 0 0</li>
  <li data-position="0" data-position2="0">Item 0 0</li>
  <li data-position="0" data-position2="0">Item 0 0</li>
  <li data-position="3" data-position2="14800">Item 3 14800</li>
  <li data-position="3" data-position2="14801">Item 3 14801</li>
  <li data-position="24" data-position2="40501">Item 24 40501</li>
  <li data-position="24" data-position2="40549">Item 24 40549</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you it does work great. Thank you very much mate. After 6 min - I'll be able to accept it.

Comment: @whitesiroi : glad to help you :)

Comment: Is it possible to do sort like that if there are strings instead of numbers as attributes? My case is: first attribute is department name, the second attribute is user name.

Comment: @frenkyb use `locaeCompare` method

Answer (score 5):

You can do this

```js
var sort = $('li').sort(function(a, b) {
  return Number($(b).data('position')) - Number($(a).data('position')) ||
    Number($(b).data('position2')) - Number($(a).data('position2'))
});

$('ul').empty().append(sort)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listitems">
  <li data-position="24" data-position2="40500">Item 24 40500</li>
  <li data-position="1" data-position2="90500">Item 1 90500</li>
  <li data-position="0" data-position2="0">Item 0 0</li>
  <li data-position="0" data-position2="0">Item 0 0</li>
  <li data-position="0" data-position2="0">Item 0 0</li>
  <li data-position="3" data-position2="14800">Item 3 14800</li>
  <li data-position="3" data-position2="14801">Item 3 14801</li>
  <li data-position="24" data-position2="40501">Item 24 40501</li>
  <li data-position="24" data-position2="40549">Item 24 40549</li>
</ul>
```